# How do I increase timer speed every 100 points c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make typing game for my assignment and I stumbled upon a problem. How do I increase the game speed by 5 every 100 points. I noticed that using timer1.Interval -=5; is wrong, so how do I do it right?

```
namespace project
```

{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
int points=0;
Label[] L;
Random r = new Random();
const int N = 3;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        
          timer1.Start();
    }
   

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (L[i].Text == Convert.ToString(e.KeyCode))
            {
                L[i].Top = 0;
                L[i].Left = r.Next(0, panel1.Width - L[i].Width);
                L[i].Text = Convert.ToString((char)r.Next(65, 90));
                points += 10;
                label4.Text = "Points " + points;

            }
            
        }
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        L = new Label[N];
        L[0] = label1;
        L[1] = label2;
        L[2] = label3;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            L[i].AutoSize = false;
            L[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            L[i].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            L[i].Width = 25;
            L[i].Height = 25;
            L[i].Top = 0;
            L[i].Left = r.Next(0, panel1.Width - L[i].Width);
            L[i].Text = Convert.ToString((char)r.Next(65, 90));
        }
    } 
  

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            L[i].Top += 2;
            if (L[i].Top + L[i].Height >= panel1.Height)
            {
                L[i].Top = 0;
                L[i].Left = r.Next(0, panel1.Width - L[i].Width);
                L[i].Text = Convert.ToString((char)r.Next(65, 90));
                points -= 5;
                label4.Text = "Points " + points;
            }
            if (points % 100==0)
            
            {
                timer1.Interval -=5;
            }
        }
    }
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        
            
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: `points % 100 == 0`

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Please give debugging details.

Comment: You could use the modulo operator as stated by others. However, this will only work if your score is exactly a multiple of 100. If for example it goes from 97 to 102, you will miss the update. 
You could also do a division to assign the interval according the current value of the score, it would work but it depends of your actual need.

Comment: if the points increase by 230 in one jump. Do you  intend to decrease the timer interval by 10 ? or still by 5?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(points % 100 == 0)
    timer1.Interval -= 5;
```

Comment: Please explain why this is the solution to the problem. It is because of [modulo](https://www.dotnetperls.com/modulo). This will divide points by 100 resulting in 0

Comment: This will only work if those 100s are actually hit exactly. If e.g. score can jump from 90 to 110, this check will fail.

Comment: Is it possible to make that even if it jumps, it will still increase through 100?